# Are Cocoa Auto Layouts Backwards Compatible?

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, constraints, backwards-compatibility

With Xcode 4 on OS X 10.7, Lion, Apple introduced a fantastic new way of handling the spacial relationships of NIB-based UI elements: [Auto Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/UnderstandingAutolayout.html).

At the top of the doc page for Auto Layouts, Apple declares:

> Note: Auto Layout is available only in Mac OS X v10.7 and later. If you are running Xcode 4 in Mac OS X v10.6, Auto Layout is not available.

At first glance, one would assume that Auto Layouts either won't compile for, or run on, pre-Lion systems. However, as I reread the notice, and doc page, it began to look like Auto Layouts just don't exist in *Xcode* on pre-Lion systems.

So do Auto Layouts, after being compiled on a Lion-based machine, work on pre-Lion machines? I would imagine that Apple could've accomplished this by compiling down the Auto Layouts into spring/strut-like settings.

[**How to disable Auto Layouts in Interface Builder**](http://www.goodbyehelicopter.com/2012/02/arggh-xcode-4-3-auto-layout-is-on-by-default-how-to-turn-off-auto-layout/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The autolayout "engine" doesn't exist in AppKit.framework on systems prior to 10.7, so your earlier thinking was correct: apps using autolayout will not run on 10.6 and earlier.